# how to add div tag to field collection

Tags: theming, javascript, entities

I have a field collection named rmr_bar_li. I want to add a div to each line item of field collection, that is within field collection. How can I do that? Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

We need to write a `hook_form_alter();`
In my case ,

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form,$form_state,$form_id) {
  form['rmr_bar_li'][und][0]['anyfield']['#suffix'] = <div class = 'class name'></div>;
}
```

Here `anyfield` is field inside the field collection below which you have to place your DIV tag.